# Помогите улучшить табы

Tags: javascript

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
$(".tab_item").not(":first").hide();
$(".top_phone .wrapper .tab").click(function() {
  $(".top_phone .wrapper .tab").removeClass("active").eq($(this).index()).addClass("active");
  $(".top_phone .tab_item").hide().eq($(this).index()).fadeIn()
}).eq(0).addClass("active");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="top_phone">
  <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="tabs">
          <span class="tab">Контактная барная стойка</span>/
          <span class="tab">Круглосуточная кухня</span>
      </div>
      <div class="tab_content">
          <div class="tab_item">
            <p class="tab_item-text">
              накормим вас в любое время дня и ночи
              <img src="img/tab-img.png" alt="">
            </p>
        </div>
           <div class="tab_item">
            <p class="tab_item-text">
              кухня
              <img src="img/tab-img.png" alt="">
            </p>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам нужно использовать [setInterval](https://learn.javascript.ru/settimeout-setinterval#setinterval), будет что то вроде

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  setInterval(function() {
    // Здесь в зависимости от потребностей пишем переключение
    // Если таба два, то можно определять тот который неактивный, убирать класс .active и добавлять к неактивному
    // Если табов больше 2, то можно использовать .eq($(this).index())
  }, 3000)
})
```

Возможно вам это все не надо и будет удобнее воспользоваться слайдером, например [bxslider](https://bxslider.com/) или любым другим где в слайды можно сделать из текста и прочих элементов.

Comment: Viacheslav Soldatov  пожалуйста, если ВАМ  не трудно покажите код полностью как должен выглядеть, а то я могу накосячить, да и другим лучше будет

Comment: Вот подробная инструкция про bxslider: https://html5book.ru/bxslider-ustanovka-nastroyki-primery/ . Я думаю вам нужно решить слайдер нужен или табы потому что не понятно зачем делать табы если контент должен автоматически переключаться.Пример слайдера с текстом: http://jsfiddle.net/syntaxys/xpvt214o/921652/

Comment: Я правильно понял, что с помощью bxslider можно сделать авто переключатели на другие вкладки.

Comment: Сейчас картинку покажу как должно выглядеть

Comment: Viacheslav Soldatov посмотрите пожалуйста картинку

Comment: По этой ссылке html5book.ru/bxslider-ustanovka-nastroyki-primery есть пример 3.4. Галерея изображений с миниатюрами. Сделайте также, замените картинки текстом и получите то что вам требуется.

Comment: Viacheslav Soldatov спасибо

Comment: Viacheslav Soldato  аможно сделать с помощью ow lcarousel (она просто уже используется)

Comment: Можно попробовать, для этого посмотрите здесь https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/demos/basic.html вероятно нужно будет задать свойство responsive 1 везде при инициализации, автопрокрутку сами найдете, далее сделайте переход на слайд по клику - на странице https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/docs/api-events.html смотрите to.owl.carousel

Comment: Viacheslav Soldatov  у меня ничего не вышло :(((